# Cannot connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-connection

I am trying to connect to **MySQL server** (hosted by **godaddy**) from **php** using **PDO**.

But I get this error :

```
An error occured : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Note that this is not a database I host.

I was simply given the username and password to construct the database, create the users etc.

```
function ConnectToDb()
{
    try{
        $dns = 'mysql:host=1.1.1.1;dbname=dummyDbName';
        $username = 'dummyUser';
        $password = 'dummyPassword';
        $LINK = new PDO($dns, $username, $password);
        $LINK->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $LINK->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        if (!$LINK){
            die('Could not connect : ' .mysql_error());
        }
        else{
            return $LINK;
        }
    } catch (PDOException $ex){
        echo "An error occured : " .$ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

I know that this works on localhost.

I'm using it no problem, but as soon as I try to connect to the **live** database it fails.

Anyone has an hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this format:

```
$user = "username";
$pass = "password";
$host = "localhost";
$db = "yourDbname";
$dns = "mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db;
$dbh = new PDO($dns, $user, $pass);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

when you have to do a query (just an example):

```
$theid = 10;
$statement = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE id = ? and name = ?');
$statement->execute(array($theid,'baronth'));
```

if you want to see if there's some errors while connecting or doing queryes (and you know how try-catch works), surround it with:

```
try {
all the code that you wan't to check
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

it will echo the error.

Comment: Just to make sure, the host is supposed to be the server address right?

Comment: Consider this code as a modal. Sometimes there can be issues when directly use: $dns = 'mysql:host=1.1.1.1;dbname=dummyDbName'; in a single quoted line.

Comment: Sorry for the late replay, ok thanks for the information will make good use of it :)  I still am not able to connect properly though, it pains me :(

Comment: Yes, finally did it. Your format helped me nail my error. It was just a host problem. Thanks a lot friend!